# Set custom ActionBar gravity to RIGHT

Tags: android

**abs_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentlay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="test"
        android:textColor="#474545"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

when i use this code to set custom ActionBar everything is fine and it shows on right side:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);
```

But when i try to change the tile of textview on my custom Actionbar using inflater, text sticks on left side:

```
   LayoutInflater mInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.abs_layout, null);
    TextView tv = mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    tv.setText("test");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomView);
```

i want it to be on right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

 <style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**custom_action_bar_layout.xml**

```
<TableRow>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_back"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/forward"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_forward"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


      </TableRow>

   </TableLayout>
```

**Android Custom Action Bar Code**

```
package com.journaldev.customactionbar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_layout);
    View view =getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

    ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_back);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    ImageButton imageButton2= (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_forward);

    imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Forward Button is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**Note : Add the following line in the AndroidManifest.xml inside the application tag.**

```
  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

it helps you